# Running json-server and protractor test on both Windows and Linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I would like to run `json-server` and then a `protractor` test on both Windows and Linux. For now, I have two configurations, one for Linux and one for Windows. Relevant part from `packages.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "json-server --watch testdb.json --static ./src",
    "e2e-win": "npm run protractor",
    "e2e-linux": "npm run protractor",
    "pree2e-win": "start /b npm start",
    "pree2e-linux": "npm start &",
    ...
}
```

The `json-server` is started as a background process and then the `protractor` executes. Is there any way how to do this in an OS agnostic way? I simply want one target `e2e`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd the package say [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) is a good match for your example, this way in the `package.json` you can simply do in the `scripts` section (taken from one tutorial I'm going through):

```
"ng": "ng",
"serve": "ng serve --proxy-conf proxy.conf.json",
"api": "json-server --watch api/data.json --routes api/routes.json",
"start_custom": "concurrently \"npm run api \" \"npm run serve\""
```

Finally just run on the command line `npm run start_custom`